# Guild Wars 2 - Dead Equipment

Tags: guild-wars-2

Throughout Guild Wars 2, you acquire equipment and accessories that once they become obsolete, become 'dead'.

What I mean by this is that the equipment cannot be sold, nor can it be recycled in any way.

So, what can I do with it?

Comment: I'd have thought your "can't be recycled in any way" comment meant they can't be thrown in the Mystic Toilet, but you never know. As @Chippies said, the only other option is to destroy them. Also note, though, that some items seem "useless" for most of the year but can be traded to vendors only during certain festivals, etc. The more interesting question might've been, where can I find a definite list of such "dead equipment", as you call it, so that I can destroy items I won't ever need again without later wanting to kick myself where it hurts... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either destroy these items (right click -> destroy) or forge 4 items of same quality into  a new item at the [Mystic Forge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge#Equipment)